# ros_lib not created installing arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

running a fresh install of hydro on a fresh install of ubuntu Precise.  According to the tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

under 3.3 Install ros_lib into the Arduino Environment

"The preceding installation steps created ros_lib, which must be copied into the Arduino build environment to enable Arduino programs to interact with ROS."

ros_lib was not created. any ideas? I rechecked everything in the install, all is well, no error messages etc.

Also, it says to put ros_lib in the libraries folder of the sketchbook. My libraries are at /usr/share/arduino/libraries

Does it matter?

regards, Richard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110451/ros_lib-not-created-installing-arduino/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros_lib should be installed in your Arduino "sketchbook/libraries". To install the ros_lib in the sketchbook use `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <sketchbook>/libraries/` . You will have to make the libraries folder and the sketchbook should automatically be generated in the home directory after the Arduino IDE is opened once.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-02-27**:
it should be rosrun and not ros

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-02-28**:
Sorry, you are correct.